How to convert silicon primitive cell to simple cubic (conventional) cell
my question above was given to me from my professer about 4 weeks ago.
and I couldn't answer properly at every time of the lab meetings.
I'm very confused about the transition between these two.
What i know is

It is a conversion of fcc to sc(simple cubic) in the Silicon.
the number of fcc basis is 2.
simple cubic basis seems to be orthogonal each other.

then how can i get the basis of simple cubic structure of Silicon?
what am i missing..?
Is it really the conversion from a "basis" of one to another?
If so, how to do that?
I searched hard sufficiently but thare are no answers compared to my efforts.
give me some hints!
I sufficiently know about vector calculus so mathematical explanation
is also welcome :)
thank you.

Do you mean this? The primitive cell isn't cubic though.

you should list the crystallographic data you are using. In any case, it seems to me you're misleading the concept of 'primitive'. In the Title you ask how to convert a primitive cell, then, in the text, you write that you want to convert a fcc structure (that is not primitive)

@JohnRennie yes. those things you showed me are the basis of primitive cell of fcc in my professer's saying. if these are called a,b,c then i can't expect new basis in sc would become (because i don't know yet this is true) a'=a+c-b, b'=b+a-c, c'=c+b-a. By simple algebra, it seems to work though.

@gryphys i confess to have poor understanding about sentences or words. my professer also indicated that. thank you for notifying me :)

fcc most certainly is a Bravais lattice which has primitive cells. The Wigner-Seitz primitive cell is a commonly used one. It is an interesting exercise to draw the Wigner-Seitz cell for simple cubic.
